# Trying to resize a image used for a button label in swiftUI

Tags: xcode, button, swiftui, image-resizing, image-size

Im trying to create a Hstack in Swift with two buttons side by side using an image as the label to create coloured buttons.

However i cant work out how to resize an image label.

Ive created an array of Strings linked to images by title

let buttonColours = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue", "Grey", "Orange"]

I've then created a Hstack where i've put two buttons side by side

```
 HStack() {
                    
                    Button{
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(buttonColours[0])
                    }
                    
              
                    
                    Button{
                        
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(buttonColours[1])
                    }
                   
                  
                    
                        }
```

This works just fine until i add the Image labels, but now i cant work out how to change the size of these buttons, i've read elsewhere that i can edit the size of images using

```
var body: some View {
        Image("myImage")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

but i can't seem to use this code to edit the button image / button sizes

ive tried

```
  Button{
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(buttonColours[0])
                    } 
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

and other variations, but i get the error

Value of type 'Button' has no member 'resizable'

[Screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS6NV.png)

Comment: In your last example, move the bracket from between `Image` and `.resizable()` to after the `.frame(...)`.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been closed with this incorrect "typo or problem" label. This was exactly my problem and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resizable` modifier applies to `Image`, not `Button`. You should apply it as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {            
            Button{
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)}
            
            Button{
                
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]